# How to find status of socket connection in web application?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, websocket

We are using socket programming for our web application. It working for multiple clients.

If client disconnects, how to find `socket_connection_status`? Eg: when user closes tab / browser?

Its working via cmd ([telnet](/questions/tagged/telnet)) i.e, when cmd is closed we can know connection status of that client.

Comment: @FlashThunder : we can use web sockets

Answer (score 0):

> You can use websocket library "Ratchet" which has following events

- onOpen - Called when a new client has Connected
- onMessage - Called when a message is received by a Connection
- onClose - Called when a Connection is closed
- onError - Called when an error occurs on a Connection

  ```
  class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
      }
  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    //client disconnection messege will be triggered here
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
  }
  ```

  }

see more at http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world